# Show $A-B$ is bounded if $A,\,B\subseteq\mathbb R$ are bounded

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $A,B \subseteq\mathbb R$ are two bounded sets, show that $$A-B:=\{a-b\,:\, a\in A,b\in B\}$$ is also bounded..

I understood that I need to use infimum and show it is bounded below, but how?

What I got is :

Let $M=\inf(A)$ and $N=\inf(B)$. Then, whenever $x\in A$ and $y\in B$, it holds $x\ge M$ and $y\ge N$.

$$x-y \ge M-N$$

So $x-y$ is bounded below.

Is this correct?

Comment: You need to show that $A-B$ is both bounded above and below.

Answer (score 2):

No need for infimums and supremums. If $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are upper and lower bounds (respectively) for $A$ and $\beta_1,\beta_2$ are upper and lower bounds (respectively) for $B$, then $\alpha_1-\beta_2,\alpha_2-\beta_1$ are upper and lower bounds (respectively) for $A-B$.

Answer (score 2):

The proof so far is wrong. Indeed, $$x\ge M\text{ and } y\ge N\not\Rightarrow x-y\ge M-N$$
**However**, $$x\ge M\text{ and } y\le U\implies x-y\ge M-U$$ so you might want to pair lower bounds with upper bounds.

As noticed by JimmyK4542, the proof is incomplete, because you also need to show that there exists a constant $M$ such that $x-y\le M$ for all $x\in A, y\in B$.

Comment: Thanks so much! It was really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct. You can conclude that $x-y\ge M-y,$ but you cannot conclude that $-y\ge-N,$ and so you cannot conclude that $x-y\ge M-N.$ Instead, try taking $N$ to be $\sup B.$ Do you see why this works? Do you see how to find an upper bound for $A-B$?

For an example to show you why your reasoning doesn't work, consider $A=[-1,0]$ and $B=[0,2].$ You should be able to prove that $A-B=[-3,0],$ but by your reasoning, $-1$ would be a lower bound of $A-B.$

Comment: Ahhh-! I got it now :) should've considered that as well. Thank you very much!